# While deploying angular app on aws i am getting module not found express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

[ click here to see error screenshot ][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rrM7.png
```

I was trying to deploy my angular app on Aws server I am serving dist/browser/index.html on node.js server.
I also tried installing  express using
npm install express --save but it didn't fix the issue.

while running node deploy.js in the terminal I am getting module not found “express”. I am getting this error today only.

Yesterday, I deployed the same app  without any issue

This is the code I am using in deploy.js

```
    //Install express server
    const express = require("express");
    const path = require("path");
    
    const app = express();
    
    // Serve only the static files form the dist directory
    app.use(express.static("./dist/browser"));
    
    app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/browser/index.html"));
    });
    
    // Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4300);
```

when I tried to run this command node deploy.js

I am getting this error

Please help me to fix this

Thank you

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    0|frontend | Require stack:
    0|frontend | - /var/www/html/frontend/deploy.js
    0|frontend |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
    0|frontend |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
    0|frontend |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
    0|frontend |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    0|frontend |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/frontend/deploy.js:2:17)
    0|frontend |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
    0|frontend |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    0|frontend |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    0|frontend |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    0|frontend |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
    0|frontend |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    0|frontend |   requireStack: [ '/var/www/html/frontend/deploy.js' ]
    0|frontend | }
    0|frontend | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/frontend/dist/browser/index.html'
    0|frontend | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/frontend/dist/browser/index.html'
```

Comment: Seems like npm install needs to happen where this script is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use express, you need to have its node_module installed.
Make sure that you execute `npm install` at the project level root. You should verify that the `node_modules` directory exists and contains the necessary libraries.

E.g. this is what a freshly [generated](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) express looks like

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www // entry point
├── node_modules // Required for running express app!  
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

On a side note: I don't know your concrete setup, but it might be worth it to look into a reverse proxy as [Nginx](https://nginx.org/) for your production setup.